# Send MySQL query to a remote database using listview

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview

I have a `ListView` of sports and when pressed I would like it to send a `MySQL` query to my remote database and send back the rest of the data about that sport so like:

```
SELECT * FROM SportsTable WHERE name="????"
```

So I would like a way to replace the `'????'` with the option I have pressed in the listview

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to read up on some tutorials before trying random things.

You can register for the OnItemClickListener which will hand you the pressed position. 
From there, you can use the position to get the item from your original collection. 
Any ListView tutorial will show you this.

Secondly, I hope you're not trying to connect straight into some remote DB or send a total query to some webservice which just takes any input as a query.

Answer (score 0):

> So I would like a way to replace the '????' with the option I have
>   pressed in the listview
>
> How would I go about doing this?

So most likely you are looking for parametrized statements(and i recommend use them). Simply you created statement like this:

```
select * from Sports where name = ?
```

**`?`** is called placeholder that will be replaced with value from ListView. Probably you are using `PHP` so you'll use `bindParam()` function for bind parameter to query. Have look at [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

And to be able to handle clicks over `ListView`, you need to use [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) and in onItemClick method you can get item at clicked position from your Collection.

Comment: use ? as a variable, right?

Comment: so how would I send off a PHP file containing that placeholder?